# Getting repeated values when using LISTAGG even for single field

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE source_det (
    e_id       NUMBER(10),
    sys_name   VARCHAR2(20),
    ref_id     NUMBER(10),
    sys_other  VARCHAR2(30)
);

INSERT INTO source_det VALUES(11,'SOURCE',992,null);
INSERT INTO source_det VALUES(11,'SOURCE',637,null);
INSERT INTO source_det VALUES(11,'SOURCE',null,'Manual');
INSERT INTO source_det VALUES(11,'TARGET',637,null);

commit;
CREATE TABLE type_fields (
  e_id      NUMBER(10),
  field_name   VARCHAR2(20),
  integer_value NUMBER(10)
);

INSERT INTO type_fields VALUES(11,'US',123); 

CREATE TABLE lookup_tab (
  l_id   NUMBER(10),
  l_value VARCHAR2(20)
);

INSERT INTO lookup_tab VALUES(123,'Unit');

--My query

SELECT sd.e_id,
       LISTAGG(CASE
                 WHEN sd.sys_name = 'SOURCE' THEN
                  sd.ref_id
               END,
               ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ref_id DESC) AS source,
       LISTAGG(CASE
                 WHEN sd.sys_name = 'TARGET' THEN
                  sd.ref_id
               END,
               ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY sd.ref_id DESC) AS target,
       LISTAGG(CASE
                 WHEN sd.sys_name = 'SOURCE' AND sd.ref_id IS NULL THEN
                  DECODE(sd.sys_other,'()','',sd.sys_other)
               END,
               ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 0) AS source_other,
       LISTAGG(CASE WHEN tf.field_name = 'US' THEN l_value END,';')BU
  FROM source_det sd
  LEFT JOIN type_fields tf ON(sd.e_id = tf.e_id)
  LEFT JOIN(SELECT l_id, l_value FROM lookup_tab)lt ON(lt.l_id = tf.integer_value)
 GROUP BY sd.e_id;
```

From the above set of data I need only a single row to be returned from the SELECT query but I am getting null values instead along with the required values. If sys_name is SOURCE then the result should be ref_id. If there is more than one record then it should be spilitted by delimiter ; If sys_name is TARGET then result should be ref_id If sys_name is SOURCE AND ref_id is null then it should give sys_other as a result. But from my query I am not getting a single row instead getting 4 rows. But ideally, I need only one row with e_id 11 And most important is in place of null values it could be possible that there would be () present in place of null. So, need to exclude this as well. All these things are handled in my query but I need to join one transaction table i.e type_fields with the reference table lookup_tab to get the respective value from the lookup table. But in my query

```
LISTAGG(CASE WHEN tf.field_name = 'US' THEN l_value END,';')BU
```

This is giving result set as -- "Unit;Unit;Unit" three times but ideally it should give me only once. But also handle if there are any other value except Unit. Then it should separate the data as "Unit;new value(just an example)" .Rest all of the things are working as expected expect the column BU.

Expected Output:

```
E_ID SOURCE  TARGET  SOURCE_OTHER SOURCE
------ ------- ------ ------------ -------
   11 992;637  637    Manual        Unit
```

Current output:

```
E_ID SOURCE  TARGET  SOURCE_OTHER      SOURCE
------ ------- ------ ------------     -------
   11 992;637  637    Manual        Unit;Unit;Unit;Unit
```

Can someone let me know where it went wrong?

Tool used: SQL Devloper(18c)

Comment: To remove repetitions you may use `distinct` keyword inside aggregate function (`listagg` supports it at least in 12+). If you want to remove it logically (by restricting the input) please provide some sample data and expected output to reproduce the problem

Comment: If your database was on 19c, you could use the `DISTINCT` keyword in your BU column like this: `LISTAGG (DISTINCT CASE WHEN tf.field_name = 'US' THEN l_value END, ';')    BU`

Comment: @astentx Currently I have 18c only so can't use ```distinct``` but I have posted the expected output. Could you please help on the same

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really doing anything wrong, it's just that all the rows generated by your joins get the same Unit value.

It's a bit messy, but you could push the main query - minus the aggregation - into a CTE, and then use a subquery to get distinct BU values to aggregate:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT sd.e_id,
         CASE
           WHEN sd.sys_name = 'SOURCE' THEN
            sd.ref_id
         END AS source,
         CASE
           WHEN sd.sys_name = 'TARGET' THEN
            sd.ref_id
         END AS target,
         CASE
           WHEN sd.sys_name = 'SOURCE' AND sd.ref_id IS NULL THEN
            DECODE(sd.sys_other,'()','',sd.sys_other)
         END AS source_other,
         CASE WHEN tf.field_name = 'US' THEN l_value END BU
    FROM source_det sd
    LEFT JOIN type_fields tf ON(sd.e_id = tf.e_id)
    LEFT JOIN lookup_tab lt ON(lt.l_id = tf.integer_value)
)
SELECT e_id,
       LISTAGG(source, ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY source DESC) AS source,
       LISTAGG(target, ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY target DESC) AS target,
       LISTAGG(source_other, ';') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY 0) AS source_other,
       (
         SELECT LISTAGG(bu, ';')
         FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT bu
           FROM cte cte2
           WHERE cte2.e_id = cte.e_id
         )
       ) AS BU
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY e_id;
```

| E_ID | SOURCE | TARGET | SOURCE_OTHER | BU |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 992;637 | 637 | Manual | Unit |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=68b72f6373329a597e7454f2165af130)

If you can have, and want to eliminate, duplicates in the other aggregates you can do the same thing got those column expressions.